# how to get flag values based on conditions in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a question about SQL Server: how to get flag values based on pid?

If name values A and Name value B corresponding id values is 1 then flag 1 other wise 0

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLECHECK]
(
    [ID] [INT] NULL,
    [NAME] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [PID] [INT] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO    

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TABLECHECK] ([ID], [NAME], [PID]) 
VALUES (1, N'A', 1), (0, N'B', 1), (1, N'A', 2),
       (1, N'B', 2), (0, N'A', 3), (0, N'B', 3)
```

Based on this data, I want to get an output like this:

```
PID  | Flag
-----+-------
1    | 0
2    | 1
3    | 0
```

My query:

```
select 
    pid, count(id),
    case 
       when name in ('a', 'b') and id = 1 
          then 1 
          else 0 
    end 
from
    [TABLECHECK]  
group by 
    pid
```

This query is resulting in an error.

Please tell me how to achieve this task in SQL Server.

Comment: ***WHAT*** error ?!?!  Please: we cannot see and read your screen, nor can we read your mind - you have to **SHOW US!**

Answer (score 1):

If A & B always exists per PID, you can do this

```
SELECT  PID,
        Flag    = CASE WHEN MIN(ID) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM    TABLECHECK 
GROUP BY PID
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SQL Server 2012, you can use `MIN()`, `IIF()` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT  PID,
        IIF(MIN(ID) = 1, 1, 0) Flag
FROM    TABLECHECK 
GROUP BY PID;
```